# Fetch & Show certain rows in a Table on clicking a button in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm pretty new when it comes to Laravel & I've been trying to code this mini-account management system where I can insert accounts manually alongside their companies & salaries and delete them (pretty basic CRUD) - I'm showing these database entries in a table. Now I want to take things further by creating a button that'll re-fetch the table data and only show accounts with salary over $40,000 - and I'm kinda confused on how I approach something like this.

This is my AccountsController.php:

```
public function showsalary(Account $account) 
{
    $query = DB::table('accounts')->where('salary','>=','45000')->get();
    $ordersalaries = $query;
    return view ('accounts',compact('ordersalaries'));
}
```

Web.php:

```
Route::get('showsalary', 'AccountsController@showsalary')->name('accounts.showsalary');
Route::resource('/accounts','AccountsController');
```

And when I try to echo the rows in 'ordersalaries' variable, it says that it's not defined. Was hoping someone can show me how do I trigger the fetching on clicking a button and what am I doing wrong / missing here, thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you show your `accounts` view?

Comment: `@foreach ($ordersalaries as $ordersalary)
                            <p>{{ $ordersalary }}</p>
                        @endforeach`

Comment: you ment `@foreach ($ordersalaries as $ordersalary) <p>{{ $ordersalary->salary }}</p> @endforeach` right ?

Comment: This looks like the `$ordersalaries` variable should be available in the view. Maybe try `return view('accounts')->with('ordersalaries', $ordersalaries);` instead to see if maybe the `compact()` call is messing it up? Also have you tried to `var_dump($ordersalaries);` in the controller to verify you are getting something back?

Answer (score 0):

**in your controller**

```
public function showsalary(Account $account) 
{
    $queries = DB::table('accounts')->where('salary','>=','45000')->get();

    return view ('accounts',compact('queries'));
}
```

**write this code in your view blade file.**

```
@foreach ($queries as $query)
 {{ $query->salary }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: can you get your answer?@VenoM

Comment: Tried, same error "undefined variable ordersalaries"